# What pre-processing methods do I need for Timestamp, Duration data for use with DBSCAN?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a month's worth of data that is in the form of:

```
            timestamp  duration
0 2015-10-01 00:00:08    2912.0
1 2015-10-01 00:48:58      30.0
2 2015-10-01 00:49:58     229.0
3 2015-10-01 00:54:07    4122.0
4 2015-10-01 02:03:19       0.0
...
```

And I wish to perform clustering based on the dimensions 'time of day in HH:MM:SS' and 'Duration' using DBSCAN from the scikit-learn library,

I understand that there needs to be a preprocessing step before using clustering but I do not know which one to use!

Would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by pre-processing? If you mean reading in the timestamp as a datetime and duration as floats then you can do this and then perform DBSCAN

Comment: Hi @EdChum thanks for your reply! I wanted to know if there are some pre-processing procedures I should use; e.g Scaling, Binarizing, Normalizing before applying clustering on it.

Comment: Depends on how you want your clusters to look like. If you're interested in similar durations in similar part of day, you can as well extract day, hour, minute.. into separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here a dummy answer:
I am in a similar situation with a classification problem. Classification algorithms are not so different to clustering ones results-wise, since the goal is to group them by similar patterns.

You can google "Pre-processing techniques for classification of mixed data" or similar.

The main idea is to convert the time stamp into "categorical variables" and binarizing them later, so you will have year: 1,0,1,1,1, etc., month:1,0,0,0,0,0,0,... (for january with 12 variables),... or you could also divide the months in seasons, so you would have 4 seasons, etc. You need to understand what is really correlated with the expected output, though.
i.e., 4 independent variables.

Hope it helps!